# Palindrome function algorithm

Tags: python, string, loops

Kinda a newbie in python, starting to lean on how python works with strings and iteration over strings.
Had worked on a chunk of so-called code 'Palindrome', would you take a look at which part exactly it is going wrong?

```
def palindrome(s):
    if len(s) < 1:
        return True
    else:
        i = 0
        j = len(s) - 1
        r = s[::-1]
        print "s is %s" % s,
        print "r is %s" % r
        while s[j] == r[i] and j != 0:
            print "s[j] is %s" % s[j],
            print "; r[i] is %s" % r[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1
        return True
    return False
```

I've used all those print statements to make sure where does the code going. The program is supposed to compare a string's and its reversed defining whether it is a palindrome or not.

Comment: You say it's wrong, but how is it wrong? Do you get an exception? The wrong result? If so, on what test data?

Answer (score 4):

Below you have a little less complicated solution:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

In your version you are always returning `True` for all strings with `len(s) >= 1`

Comment: nice its too simple in Python :)

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, guess you're totally right. the functions returns true for all the string greater than 1.

Comment: yeah.. I've edited this as I misunderstood the question - I thought about "word from which palindrome could be built" (:

Answer (score 1):

I may be missing something obvious, but shouldn't this be enough?

```
def ispalindrome(s):
   return s == s[::-1]
```